# Splitting field and intermediate fields

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

Find splitting field $K$ of polynomial $x^3-7$ over $\mathbb{Q} (\sqrt{3} )$ and find

1. $(K: \mathbb{Q} )$
2. $G(K/ \mathbb{Q} )$
3. Find intermediate fields between $\mathbb{Q}$ and $K$.

So the splitting field is $K=\mathbb{Q} ( \sqrt{3}, \epsilon _3, \sqrt[3]{7}) = \mathbb{Q} (\sqrt{3},i,\sqrt[3]{7})$ and

1. $(K: \mathbb{Q} ) = 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 =12$
2. $G(K/ \mathbb{Q} ) = \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_3$ as 
   $\sqrt{3} \mapsto \pm \sqrt{3}  $ , $i \mapsto \pm i$, $\sqrt[3]{7} \mapsto \sqrt[3]{7} $ or $\sqrt[3]{7} \mapsto \epsilon _3 \sqrt[3]{7}$ or $\sqrt[3]{7} \mapsto \epsilon _3 ^2 \sqrt[3]{7}$.

Can someone check if I am right?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You are wrong with your computation of the Galois group: if the Galois group were abelian then all subfields would be Galois over $\mathbf Q$, yet one of the subfields is ${\mathbf Q}(\sqrt[3]{7})$, which is not Galois over ${\mathbf Q}$. As a simpler problem, can you compute the Galois group of the splitting field of $x^3 - 7$ over ${\mathbf Q}$?

Comment: As $K$ is a splitting field of a cubic, the Galois group $G(K/\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt3))$ has to be a subgroup of $S_3$. Because it is of order six, it cannot be abelian (has to be all of $S_3$). So your Galois group cannot be abelian either (it has a non-abelian subgroup). Observe that if $\sqrt3\mapsto\sqrt3$ and $i\mapsto-i$, then $\epsilon_3\mapsto\epsilon_3^2$.